Building a Display Banner project built on Vanilla HTML, CSS, and JS with Vite 2.0
Context:
I have a display ad project where my src has folders for different sizes and each folder contains the HTML, CSS, JS, and other assets that would be required to load that Display Banner. Something like this:

So far, I've compressed the HTML, CSS, JS, and assets to a zip file and moved it to a folder with its own name, something like this:

We then share this COM-XXX folder with our partners to dispatch the display ad.
I wanted to automate this process using Vite so that it could generate this folder with vite build.
Considerations:
I'm stuck with Node v14.16.1 and can't update it due to enterprise concerns. So I'm using Vite v2.9.18.
My vite.config.js looks like this:
const { resolve } = require("path");
const { defineConfig } = require("vite");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  root: resolve(__dirname, "src"),
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: [
        "160x600",
        "300x250",
        "300x600",
        "320x50",
        "720x90",
        "970x250",
      ].reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc[item] = resolve(__dirname, "src", item, "index.html");
        return acc;
      }, {}),
    },
    esbuild: {
      exclude: /\.html?$/, // Exclude HTML files from ESBuild transpilation
    },
    outDir: resolve(__dirname, "dist"), // specify the output directory
    emptyOutDir: true, // clear the output directory before build
  },
});

And, the build output looks something like this:

Issue:
As of now, it's generating separate folders for the HTML files. But it's not generating the JS files. And it's moving the CSS and asset files to a common assets folder.
How do I update my vite.config.js to make it output the JS, CSS, and asset files(images/fonts etc.) all in the same folders as the HTML for each individual size?
Things I've tried:
I've tried using the vite-plugin-html plugin to make it generate the assets, CSS, and JS all in the same folder, but it's not doing that.
Thanks in advance.
